# deploying angular 4 app through iis

Tags: angular, iis

I am using `ng build --prod --base-href=/my folder/subfolder/`
And also I have copied the `dist` folder inside the above mentioned subfolder.

In IIS I have provided the physical path, but when browsing blank screen is coming without any error.

Comment: i can suggest what i did for node.js and maybe it can help you also: So, i didn't touch the` base href `in the project or in the` ng build` and in the node.js app for `GET` `/` requests I respond with the `index.html` from the `dist `folder. `res.sendFile(`${frontEndDist}/index.html`);`

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: great! I added it as answer to be more clear - if you want you can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest what i did for node.js and maybe it can help you also: So, i didn't touch the`base href in the project or in the ng build` and in the node.js app for GET / requests I respond with the index.html from the dist folder. `res.sendFile(${frontEndDist}/index.html)`;